# trying to wrap a structure with another set of structure

Tags: struct, coldfusion, lucee

I am trying to wrap a structure with another structure, but definitely i am missing something

i want to show it like this

```
account: {
    "name": "Example Account",
    "details": "https://www.example.com"
  }
```

i am trying this function, but i am missing something, probably i should use structmap, not sure

```
<cffunction name="SO">
    <cfargument name="name" required="true" type="struct">
    <cfargument name="data" required="true" type="struct">
    <cfloop collection="#arguments.Data#" index="i">
        <cfset arguments.Name['#lcase(i)#'] = arguments.Data[i]>
    </cfloop>   
    <cfreturn arguments.Name>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: It's hard to diagnose the problem without a sample of the input. What do the two input structures look like?

Comment: one is form and another one i want to nest that form into an object i pass

Comment: Updating the question with sample values will make it much easier to understand.

Comment: https://trycf.com/gist/bc30e54714f689c9d4db716c824bacf5/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: That's the expected output. I'm asking about *input*. The function takes two structures. Could you post an example of those?

Comment: not two structures, one is string which is account to be converted to a structure with a function and the other two are form values

Comment: Are talking about something like the `DeserializeJSON()` function?

Comment: Chacha - the cfargument definitions say both are type struct. Could you post a complete example so we can observe the issue you are describing?

Comment: i messed up, the first argument shoud be a string

Comment: Maybe someone else will understand better, but it's difficult to visualize the issue without the starting input values.

Comment: @chacha Now reading back over your last comments, I'm not sure if my answer gets what you're looking for. As Agreax said, provide an example of the INPUT to the function so that we can better see your intent. Also, you talk about the supplied values being one string and two form values. This is why we need an example of input. Your data above appears to be only two inputs, an "name" string and a "data" struct.

Comment: Also, how is this data coming to the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I first looked at this, I thought you essentially wanted to have a new struct with a "name" (containing a string) and a "data" containing a struct.

Your initial setup is essentially

```
<cfset name = "Test" >
<cfset data = { details: "detail1" , details2: "detail2" } >
```

When dealing with most data structures in CF, I usually find it much easier and cleaner to work with CFSCRIPT instead of tags. So I came up with

```
<cfscript>
    function SO ( required String name, required Struct data ) {
        var retval = { name:"",data:{} } ;

        retval.name = arguments.name ;

        arguments.data.map( function(key, val) {
            retval.data[key.lcase()] = val ;
        } ) ;

        return retval;
    }

    writedump( SO(name,data) ) ;
</cfscript>
```

Trying to unwind this, it appears that all you're trying to do is add a "name" value to your "data" struct. This can easily be done with

```
<cffunction name="SO_tags">
    <cfargument name="name" required="true" type="string">
    <cfargument name="data" required="true" type="struct">

    <cfset retval2 = arguments.data >
    <cfset retval2.name = arguments.name>
    <cfreturn retval2>
</cffunction>

<cfset structure = {"account":SO_tags(name,data)}>
<cfdump var = #structure#>
```

Or using script, it can come down to just a single line.

```
<cfscript>
    function SO3 ( required String name, required Struct data ) {
        return arguments.data.append( {"name":arguments.name} ) ;
    }

writedump( {"account":SO3(name,data)} ) ;
</cfscript>
```

Depending on how this fits into the rest of your code, you may not even need a function.

https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=b6e92a83-ebc9-40eb-a712-f402d7f9ed85/f4fb9f8e-3b60-4a64-8c02-2cd106736df0/4e00abae-b949-4934-86e8-870745259127.cfm

EDIT: Changed output to nest it within an "account" structure.

Comment: Hi @shawn
as far as the call to the dump is concerbed : `<cfset structure = {"account":SO_tags(name,data)}>` - You are sending a structure with namee: pair values, can i send form instead of that,

Comment: i am trying to use it like this : `SO(name = "account",data = form)` - but it seems not working

Comment: @chacha Just like your previous comment should work. What does "not working" mean? What error or behavior are you getting?